# Jquery Slider to start from second slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wanting to create a content slider similar to the image I have attached. I am wondering if by taking a normal content slider and setting overflow to visible I will be able to show the 3 slides. But is it possible for the slider to have slide2 positioned in the area that would normally be visible?

[slider image http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/3994/sliderew.jpg](http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/3994/sliderew.jpg)

jsfiddle.net/craigie2204/WMF2N/2

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// Setup Variables
var slides = $('#slider_mask .slide_container').children();
var total_slides = slides.length; // ***CHANGED***
var slide_width = $('#slider_mask').width();
var current_slide = 0;

// ***REMOVED*** slides.not(':first').hide();
// Set the width of the slide_container to total width of all slides
$('#slider_mask .slide_container').width(slide_width*total_slides);

slides.width(slide_width); // ***ADDED***

// Handle Right Arrow Click
$('#slider_mask .right_button').on('click', function() {

current_slide++;

if(current_slide == total_slides){ current_slide = 0; }

var negative_margin_required = current_slide*slide_width;
$('#slider_mask .slide_container').stop().animate({marginLeft:-      negative_margin_required+'px'},'fast');


});

// Handle Left Arrow Click
$('#slider_mask .left_button').on('click', function() {

current_slide--;

if(current_slide < 0){ current_slide = total_slides-1; }

var negative_margin_required = current_slide*slide_width;
$('#slider_mask .slide_container').stop().animate({marginLeft:-    negative_margin_required+'px'},'fast');

});
});
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Show the code you're working on so that someone can improve it.

Comment: what slider plugin are you using?

Comment: All you ask is possible in jquery, so you don´t need to wonder anymore and try doing it. If you get stuck ... show us your code in we can try helpng you.

Comment: We have no idea what you are using.... PROVIDE CODE!

Comment: As previously mentioned, you should provide some code for others to help you out and be more specific about what slider and or libraries you are using.

Comment: Here is a simple Fiddle just needs to start at slide 2 cheers 

http://jsfiddle.net/craigie2204/WMF2N/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your fiddle, and without getting into the code to deep you can use this:

```
var current_slide = 1;
$('#slider_mask .slide_container').css('marginLeft', -current_slide*slide_width+'px');
```

With this you can start at any slide your want by setting the initial value of `current_slide`.

Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/bMv6P/

Answer (score 3):

You can add this into the javascript after you get the slidewidth:

```
    $('#slider_mask .slide_container').css({marginLeft:-slide_width+'px'});
```

or just set the margin property in css to the fixed slidewidth.

here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WMF2N/3/

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work solely. Vou also have to set `current_slide` to `1`. Try it in your fiddle. The sliding is not working right straight from the beginning.

Comment: @insertusernamehere it works in my jsfiddle ... it basicaly does the same as yours but with a bit less code and operations ... cause i just call slide_width and dont multiply it with the slide number =)

Comment: The only difference in this line is that it's multiplied (if the OP want's to start in slide 3 for example). But apart from that: If your first click is *right*, nothing happens, you have to hit it twice. If the first click is *left* it slides right one time. :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere you are right. I just felt a bit defensive at first ;-) Well your answer got accepted and you got my vote too =)

Comment: Hey, I didn't wanted to offend you. It should've been just a note that a little piece was missing. :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere no worries, no offense taken =)